# sequential function call, while one of them uses setTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I want to call three functions `someTask1`, `someTask2` and `someTask3` in that order. However, the function `someTask2` involves Ajax call, and keep calling itself recursively using `setTimeout` unless a *desired* value is return. The code looks like this:

```
doListOfTasks: function(myparam){
    var someObj = someTask1(myParam);
    someTask2(someObj);
    someTask3(someObj);
},
someTask2: function(someObj){
    $.ajax({
          url: "someUrl.do",
          type: "POST",
          data: ({"id": rowObject.instanceId}),
          dataType: "json",
          async:false,
          success: function(res){
              if(res.prop1 != 'desired'){
                  setTimeout(function(){someTask2(someObj);}, 2000);
              }
          }
       }
    );
},
```

As you might have guessed, the execution of this code does not wait for `someTask2` to return before calling `someTask3`.

I want the code inside `doListOfTasks` to be executed sequentially. How can I do that?

Also, I do not want to hard-code  `someTask3` in `success` callback. E.g. I do not want to do this:

```
          success: function(res){
              if(res.prop1 != 'desired'){
                  setTimeout(function(){someTask2(someObj);}, 2000);
              }else{
                  someTask3(someObj);
              }

          }
```

How can achieve this?

Thanks

---

*Edit#1*

The problem is not being able to call the functions... but the problem is synchronization. I want `someTask2` to finish whatever it's doing, and *only then* `someTask3` is called.

`someTask2` calls itself repetitively using setTimeout... I guess this triggers a new thread and `someTask2` is returned after first call... triggering `someTask3` in main thread.  However, separate thread spawns (and gets killed) in each call setTimeout until the desired criteria is met.

That's why, while the someTask2 still looping, the call to someTask3 triggers.

Not sure how correct I am.

Comment: You basically have it right, although JavaScript only has one thread of execution. Only one task can run at once, although internally the browser *could* use different threads for book-keeping such as keeping track of timers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using a **`Deferred`** in jquery:

```
$.when(someTask1(), someTask2(), someTask3()).then(successFunc, errorFunc);
```

You need to return a custom made `.Deferred` object with a promise value.

```
someTask2: function(someObj)
{
    var def = $.Deferred();

    $.ajax({
          url: "someUrl.do",
          type: "POST",
          data: ({"id": rowObject.instanceId}),
          dataType: "json",
          async:false,
          success: function(res){
              if(res.prop1 != 'desired'){
                  setTimeout(function(){someTask2(someObj);}, 2000);
              }
              else
              {
                def.resolve(res);
              }
          }
       }
    );

    return def.promise();
}
```

So for example:

```
function someTask1()
{
    var def = $.Deferred();
    def.resolve('i\'m data resolved from task1');
    return def.promise();
}

function someTask2(someObj)
{
    var def = $.Deferred();

    var count = 0;
    var f = function() {
        console.log(++count);
        if (count > 2) {
            def.resolve('whoop we got the value we wanted in task 2 after many tries: ' + count);
        }
        else
            setTimeout(f, 1000);
    };
    f();
    return def.promise();
}

function someTask3()
{
    var def = $.Deferred();
    def.resolve('and hello from task3!');
    return def.promise();  
}

var success = function(x) {
  console.log('success:', arguments);
};

var error = function() {
      console.log('oh no an error occured in one of the tasks.');
};

$.when(someTask1(), someTask2(), someTask3()).then(success , error);
```

Will show

```
1
2
3
success: ["i'm data resolved from task1",
          "whoop we got the value ...k 2 after many tries: 3",
           "and hello from task3!"]
```

**fiddle available:** http://jsfiddle.net/garreh/29SW7/

Comment: Remember to change your tasks so they are like `yourObject.someTask2(someObj);`

Comment: thanks for the answer, I have learnt a thing or two. But the problem stays.`$.when(someTask2(someObj), someTask3(someObj)).then(function(){alert('finished');});` the functions are still not called in order. May be it's the setTimeout creating problem.

Comment: +1 for introducing to a really cool feature. Updated the question.

Comment: All your functions will need to be instances of the Deferred object. As of jQuery 1.5 the .ajax object automatically implements the object, so you don't need to make it a Deferred object. Alternatively, you could do something like this: `$(someTask1(), someTask2()).then(function() { someTask3(); }, errorFunc)`

Comment: Yes. Reading on. Here is a good article I think worth mentioning, [Using Deferreds in jQuery 1.5](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/using-deferreds-in-jquery/)

Comment: I've updated the answer, hopefully should get you on the right track with your new Deferred friends ;-)

Comment: This is simply great. Thank you very much. Marking as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass a callback to `someTask2`. For example:

```
someTask2: function(someObj, callback){
$.ajax({
      url: "someUrl.do",
      type: "POST",
      data: ({"id": rowObject.instanceId}),
      dataType: "json",
      async:false,
      success: function(res){
          if(res.prop1 != 'desired'){
              setTimeout(function(){someTask2(someObj, callback);}, 2000);
          } else {
             if (callback != null) { 
                 callback(); 
             }
          }
      }
   }
);
}
```

Then just pass `someTask3` as the callback:

```
someTask2(someObj, function (){ someTask3(someObj); });
```

Comment: yes, this will be the last resort.. I really wanted to avoid it. Updated question, BTW.

Comment: I wouldn't be afraid to go with an approach like this. Callbacks are a very common pattern when working with jQuery and Ajax, since often you have functions that you need to execute after an asynchronous operation. That said, Deferred is probably a better choice if you are using jQuery 1.5 - especially once (if) you do this in other places in your application.

Comment: Absolutely. `.ajax` is a deferred object and it would be silly not to exploit it's awesome powerfulness.